# Set bamboo variable from nodejs script and use it in curl in script task

Tags: node.js, shell, bamboo

I have a `bamboo` pipeline with 2 script tasks.

1. Script task that installs npm package (working fine)
2. Script task that runs `nodejs` script and `curl` command (having issue)

In the second script task, I've

```
tee -a test.js > /dev/null <<  EOT
  nodejs script that sets a variable
  
  var signedToken = token + "." + signature;

  process.env.AuthToken = signedToken;

EOT

echo "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
node test.js
echo "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

curl --location 'https://test.com/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: ${bamboo.AuthToken}' \ not working
--data '{ }'
```

In the `curl` command, how do I set header Authorization to a value of a variable (signedToken in this case) that gets set in `nodejs` script?

Answer (score 1):

`process.env` is your node process. You need a way to expose your `signedToken` to the current shell process. One such way is print the token to stdout and catch it in bash, assuming your node script doesn't produce any other output. Here's the gist of it:

```
tee -a test.js > /dev/null <<  EOT
...
process.stdout.write(signedToken);
EOT
...
token=$(node test.js)
...
--header "Authorization: $token"
...
```

If the node script produces other output, write the token to an external file which then your bash script will read and use in the curl command.